# How to get the text if we have a duplicate code

Tags: javascript, html, automation, protractor

```
      <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 text-center"><strong>₹. 65000</strong></td>
      <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 text-center"><strong>₹. 75000</strong></td>
```

My Script:

```
element(by.tagName('strong')).getText();
```

My Output:
`65000`

Note: Here i wanted to get the `75000` as output. Can anyone help me in resolving the issue.

Comment: I'd recommend you to start with reading protractor documentation https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.get

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this example to get only the pair elements of each tag.

```js
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("strong")[1].textContent);

for (let i = 0 ; i < document.getElementsByTagName("strong").length ; i++) {
    if (i%2) {
    console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("strong")[i%2].textContent);
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>The HTML5 Herald</title>
  <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">

</head>

<body>

<td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 text-center"><strong>₹. 65000</strong></td>
<td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 text-center"><strong>₹. 75000</strong></td>

</body>
</html>
```

But please notice this should only work if those elements are duplicated not tripled, quadrupled, etc...

The example is in vanilla javascript.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.get

use element.all and get

```
text = await element.all(by.tagName('strong')).get(2);

text = await text.getText()
```

Comment: you don't need to `await` elementFinder. I would not use the same variable for elementFinder and it's value

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov if you are not going to reuse that element then its a waste of memory to create different variables

Answer (score 0):

can you try

```
element(by.css("td:nth-child(2)).getText();
```